# jquery how to get value in a table

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the following code that generates a table:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="assignedvs">
      <thead>
          <tr>

              <th>VlId</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Voice</th>
              <th>Jumbo</th>
              <th>Mode</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

          <?php foreach ($vln as $vlndetail): ?>
              <tr>          
                     <td id='vlid'><?php echo $vlndetail['VlId'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $vlndetail['Name'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $vlndetail['Status'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $vlndetail['Voice'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $vlndetail['Jumbo'] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $vlandetail['Mode'] ?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php endforeach ?>
```

I need to find the row where the VlId matches what the user has specified in a text box.  Once I've found this record, I want to grab value in the mode column for the particular row.

here's what i've written so far:

```
    $('#delete').live('click', function()  {

                //get a count of all records. only allowed to delete if you have more than one + the header.
                var reccount = $('#assignedvs tr').length;

                if (reccount > 2)
                {
                    //loop through the table
                $('#assignedvs tr').each(function() {

                    var temp = $(this).find(".vlid").html(); 
                    console.log(temp);  
                                    if (temp == $('#uservalue').val){
                                          //grab mode column
                                     }
                });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("error: must have at least 1 record.");
                }



    });
```

problem - the code i have to reference the vlid column is incorrect.  it always prints a null to the console.
Can you tell me what I've done wrong?
thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I changed my id to a class and changed my jquery back to the original code I had. it's working - except for the fact that I think it's including the header . I have 4 rows + header. When i check the console results, the first print out is always NULL and then the correct value for the 4 records. how do it get it to ignore the header?

Comment: var temp = $(this).find("#vlid").html();

Comment: the better change would be `<td class='vlid'>` since it's inside a loop and there could be many of them on the page.

Comment: @MrOBrian - i changed my id to a class and changed my jquery back to the original code I had.  it's working - except for the fact that I think it's including the header .  I have 4 rows + header.  When i check the console results, the first print out is always NULL and then the correct value for the 4 records.  how do it get it to ignore the header?

Comment: there are a lot of ways you could skip the first row. Either with a different selector, or modify the jQuery collection to exclude the first object, or use a for loop and start with the second row.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is why it's even included?  aren't i "filtering" what i'm searching by the class? sorry... if this is a dumb questin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are `find`ing by `className`, not by `id`. To find by `id`, use the following instead:

```
$(this).find("#vlid").html();
```

**However**, since `id`s should be unique across the entire document, a better solution would be to maintain your current code, and instead of using `<td id='vlid'>`, use `<td class='vlid'>`.

Also note that `val()` is a function. Thus, to get the value of a given input, you should use `$('#uservalue').val()`.

**EDIT**: To exclude the header, use the `$('#assignedvs tbody tr')` selector. This way, you only get rows that are descendants of `tbody`, thus ignoring the header rows, which descend from `thead`.

Comment: a better fix would be to change it to a class in the element since there will be more than one.

Comment: doh! thanks.  and is there any way to skip the header as a row?

Comment: @MrOBrian - sorry I'm just new to this stuff.  can you explain your comment a little further? thank you

Comment: @dot: That's because `id`s should be unique across the entire document. Thus, instead of `<td id="vlid">`, you should have `<td class="vlid">`.

Comment: @dot: To exclude the header use `$('#assignedvs tbody tr')`, that is, you select all rows that are descendants of `tbody` thus excluding the header, which is a descendant of `thead`.

Comment: @JoãoSilva - can you please check out the section called Edit 1 in my post? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

couple of changes:

1. `<?php echo $vlndetail['VlId']; //missing semi-colon ?>`
2. `var temp = $(this).find("#vlid").html();` vlid is an id

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this via datatables at http://datatables.net

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = $(this).find("#vlid").html(); // .vlid (by class) changed to #vlid (by id)
```

Answer (score 0):

An even easier solution.

Assign an ID to each row with the *vlId* (possibly prepend `tr_` to the ID to avoid duplication).

Assign a class with the column name to each datacell.

Like so:

```
      <?php foreach ($vln as $vlndetail): ?>
          <tr id='tr_<?php echo $vlndetail['VlId'] // set the ID ?>'>          
              <td class='vlid'><?php echo $vlndetail['VlId'] ?></td>
              <td class='Name'><?php echo $vlndetail['Name'] ?></td>
              <td class='Status'><?php echo $vlndetail['Status'] ?></td>
              <td class='Voice'><?php echo $vlndetail['Voice'] ?></td>
              <td class='Jumbo'><?php echo $vlndetail['Jumbo'] ?></td>
              <td class='Mode'><?php echo $vlandetail['Mode'] ?></td>
          </tr>
      <?php endforeach ?>
```

Then to get the Name of the selected vlID just do this JQUERY:

```
var rowID = "#tr_" + $('#uservalue').val(); // this is optional. I prefer to cache values for increased code readability.
$(rowID + " td.Mode").dostuffhere(); // this selector returns the Mode cell for the row indicated by the user
```

This will grab the Mode column of that specific row.

Comment: hey thanks.  the only catch is that i don't have logic right now to find the selected row.  the way my page works right now is slightly different - based on user requirements - thanks though

Comment: Oh, so you can't change the way the table is generated to insert the row #id and the cell .classes?